# BlueZ: what are the meaning of the fields of le_set_scan_parameters_cp?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

In BlueZ there is this struct:

https://github.com/pauloborges/bluez/blob/master/lib/hci.h#L1536

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t     type;
    uint16_t    interval;
    uint16_t    window;
    uint8_t     own_bdaddr_type;
    uint8_t     filter;
} __attribute__ ((packed)) le_set_scan_parameters_cp;
```

I'm searching for the meaning of its fields. Do you have any reference by any chance?

Specifically *interval*, *window*, and **filter**. What are their meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best reference for HCI commands is the Bluetooth Core Specification which you can find at:
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/

The current Version is 5.3 and in Vol 4, Part E is HCI commands and events.

`7.8.10 LE Set Scan Parameters command` is the section you are looking for where it has the following about the filter:

[image]

and for interval and window:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this reference, very useful! Core spec contains more than 3k pages, so this was a great help to navigate myself into it. Do you maybe have any idea on where can I find more info about the filter policies? For ex.: setting the *filter policy* to 0x03, how can I specify the details of the filter?

Comment: Starting to be at the edge of my knowledge. I think it is the "4.3 LINK LAYER DEVICE FILTERING" section you need and setting "Filter Accept List". Those commands are a few pages on from the previous one. "7.8.16 LE Add Device To Filter Accept List command" in the spec should be a good place to start.